# AWS Cognito and Kibana: it does not ask for credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, kibana, amazon-cognito

We have configured Cognito and Kibana to use the Cognito pools for authentication, but when I open Kibana endpoint - it just let me in, without asking for login / password. We used [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-cognito-auth.html) doc, but IAM part isn't quite clear.

In ES cluster I see:

```
Amazon Cognito for authentication: Enabled
Cognito User Pool: my-user-pool
Cognito Identity Pool: my-id-pool
IAM Role Name: the_role_name
```

`the_role_name` has standard AWS-managed `AmazonESCognitoAccess` attached.

I'm a bit confused that at VPC we have

```
IAM Role: AWSServiceRoleForAmazonElasticsearchService
```

The identity pool has `Enable access to unauthenticated identities` disabled.

So, how to enable the authentication properly?

Answer (score 0):

There were missing permissinos in elasticsearch "access policy", was needed like that:

```
{
  "Sid": "",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1111111111:role/acl-Cognito-Auth-Role-my"
  },
  "Action": "es:ESHttp*",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:es:eu-west-1:1111111111:domain/es-name/*"
}
```

Comment: what role is this: `acl-Cognito-Auth-Role-my` ?